# Display field on form tab based on current page template

Tags: kentico

I am trying to hide fields from the form tab in Kentico if the template is not in a category. I have tried the following in visibility condition:

```
CurrentDocument.DocumentPageTemplate.PageTemplateCategory.DisplayName=="foo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the CurrentDocument with EditedObject

```
EditedObject.DocumentPageTemplate.PageTemplateCategory.CategoryDisplayName="foo"
```

if the Category eqauls foo it will be visible, otherwise no

Answer (score 2):

When working in the Kentico UI and setting field visibility always use the `EditedObject` object vs. the `CurrentDocument` object.  The `CurrentObject` object is only used during runtime of the actual page and never on the form tab.  The `EditedObject` will work with within the form tab of a page type as well as within any Kentico UI pages.

So in your case, replace `CurrentDocument` with `EditedObject` to get the correct object.